# NimbleCSV/CSV - newline in string causes csv to have extra lines

Tags: elixir

I have a character in a string that is a newline. Checking what the character is with the `?character` gives me `8232`.

It works fine when I manually wrap that field in double quotes. But how can I get the CSV to be generated with the quotes already in there?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your own CSV parser with [`NimbleCSV.define/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/nimble_csv/NimbleCSV.html#define/2), manually passing the list of codepoints you want to escape (under `:reserved` key of options, as described in the documentation)

You have provided zero information on whether you use the default [`NimbleCSV.RFC4180`](https://hexdocs.pm/nimble_csv/NimbleCSV.RFC4180.html) ISO parser or your own implementation, neither you provided the input example. Also, it is unclear whether you want to drop these or properly escape them.

So here is the most comprehensive typical example of how to handle custom codepoints and escape them.

```rb
NimbleCSV.define(Parser,
  separator: ",",
  escape: "\"",
  reserved: ["\"", ",", "\n", "\u2028"]
)
data = [~w|foo, bar|, ["|\"|", "|\u2028|"]]
Parser.dump_to_iodata(data)
#⇒ [
#   [[34, "foo,", 34], 44, "bar", 10],
#   [[34, "|\"\"|", 34], 44, [34, "| |", 34], 10]
# ]
```

As you might see, all the elements *but* `"bar"` which has no reserved codepoints, are *escaped*.